# How to get count of complete and pending task by department

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table.

Table : Department

```
ID int
Name Varchar(50)
```

Table: Task

```
Id int
ProjectId int,
TaskName varchar(50)
Status bit() -- 100 for complete else notComplete
```

Table: User

```
UserId int
DepId int
Name varchar(50),
```

Table: TeamMember

```
Id int,
UserId int,
ProjectId int
```

I just want to get count of complete and pending task by department. Here is what I tried:

```
select sub.Name,sub.result,count(*)
from (
    select tmm.userid,dp.Name,tm.id,tm.ActivityName,CASE ActualComplete WHEN 100 THEN 'done 100' ELSE 'In Complete' END as result 
    from MasterActivity tm
    inner join TeamMember_Master tmm on tmm.projectid=tm.projectid 
    inner join Users_Master us on us.UserId=tmm.userid
    inner join departments dp on us.DepartmentId=dp.id
) sub
group by sub.name,sub.result
```

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight i had wrote the following query. select sub.Name,sub.result,count(*) 
from (select tmm.userid,dp.Name,tm.id,tm.ActivityName,CASE ActualComplete WHEN 100 THEN 'done 100'  ELSE 'In Complete' END as result 
from MasterActivity tm inner join TeamMember_Master tmm on tmm.projectid=tm.projectid inner join Users_Master us on us.UserId=tmm.userid 
inner join departments dp on us.DepartmentId=dp.id)sub group by sub.name,sub.result

Comment: This is a much better question with a query!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
select dep.ID, dep.Name, sum(case when t.Status = 100 then 1 else 0 end) as Completed_Cnt, 
   sum(case when t.Status <> 100 then 1 else 0 end) as NotCompleted_Cnt 
from Task t
inner join TeamMember tm on tm.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
inner join [User] u on u.Id = tm.UserId
inner join Department dep on dep.Id = u.DepId
group by dep.Id, dep.Name
```

This should work (this is of the top of my head), but if you don't provide a minimum example with sample data and expected result, we can't help you more.

Please read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks @mihail stancescu

Comment: Don't forget to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if it helped you.  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps others to find a working solution.